# chop up a list into sub lists of length 2

Tags: python

I have a list like below (similar to below but much longer)

[123.45, 32.89, 234.90, 234.96, 56.94, 71.21]

I wish to chop it up to look like this (I need the [ and ( brackets as per this below)

[(123.45, 32.89), (234.90, 234.96), (56.94, 71.21)]

I am not professional python programmer. I use a Visual Programming Language called DynamoBIM. I occasionally have to write a little bit of Python to do stuff with DynamoBIM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/16729135

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the list against itself, both striding by `2` but one list offset one index from the other.

```
>>> data = [123.45, 32.89, 234.90, 234.96, 56.94, 71.21]
>>> list(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))
[(123.45, 32.89), (234.9, 234.96), (56.94, 71.21)]
```

Comment: Thanks this works for my script.

Answer (score 1):

A space efficient way without slicing:

```
data = [123.45, 32.89, 234.90, 234.96, 56.94, 71.21]

i = iter(data)
[*zip(i, i)]
# [(123.45, 32.89), (234.9, 234.96), (56.94, 71.21)]
```

You can do it in one go in Python >= 3.8 using an assignment expression:

```
[*zip((i := iter(data)), i)]
```

Comment: This is certainly cool, although it will only work in Python 3.8 or new (because of the walrus operator `:=`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator and `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

l = [123.45, 32.89, 234.90, 234.96, 56.94, 71.21]
i = iter(l)
[tuple(islice(i,2)) for n in range(len(l)//2)]
```

output: `[(123.45, 32.89), (234.9, 234.96), (56.94, 71.21)]`